# Other ways of setting up dynamic content in Wordpress than Posts and Pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates, content-management-system

so this might be quite a general question but I would like to know if there are other ways of making parts of webpage content editable in WP Dashboard than Posts or Pages... (thus maybe not using The Loop)

Thing is I am doing a website for a client, that doesn't need ''posts'' like in blog but there are defined sections of content that he would like to be able to edit and change in WP Dashboard (no experience with code)...

To imagine better, take an About Us page, where you have 2-3 paragraphs of text, that normally stays same, but if clients wants to add a line or two he could do it in Wordpress Dashboard in same way as in Customise -> Header (tagline change)/..

Is this normally also done with posts or is there anyway to just create more inputs in `customise` section of WP to be able to edit the content there?

Example of content

```
<section id="about">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Qui sommes nous</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row about-mta">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Phasellus bibendum commodo velit quis molestie.
                Duis volutpat in dui vel luctus. Etiam posuere pellentesque iaculis.
                Curabitur vitae consectetur ligula. Nullam leo sapien, pulvinar ac ex eu,
                convallis volutpat quam. Nullam euismod elit quis ante finibus rutrum.
                Donec felis tellus, tempus non tempus ut, gravida non magna.
                Sed consectetur magna vel dignissim consequat. Donec eu justo dui.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
```

Comment: What's your issue with using Pages?

Comment: Can you be more specific because otherwise, I have to write a small book about to answer your question correctly?

Comment: @Spartacus to be more specific let's take I have 4 sections: About us, How it Works, Team Structure, Contact.. I do not want them to be separate pages, but they are just separate sections on homepage - like rows of `divs`

Comment: So why can't you have separate sections in your static front page content? Did you set a static front page?

Comment: nope I didn't, I guess I haven't really got it right what it means to have set up as static front page? I mean I know what it means, I just don't know how it changes how wordpress processes the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the correct third way to do this, 
to be more specific the actual action is **adding more customisable fields or ''settings'' in Wordpress Dashboard / Customizer** available under *Appearance -> Customise* ..

This is done through using **Customizer API** creating a `customize.php` file in your WP theme and using `$wp_customize` functions like `add_section()`, `add_setting()` and `add_control()`..

I myself was not aware of this possibility, as other developers may not be, so if you are looking for same solution, it is well enough explained in Wordpress Developer Docs here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API